# Deploy partial updates to Jelastic

Tags: java, tomcat, jelastic

I have a project with a 26mb war file of which 25mb are library jars.  Is there a way to not have to re-deploy these jars with the war each time.

I notice in the Jelastic tomcat directory, there's the war file and then there's the uncompressed contents of the war.

Is there some way to just do incremental updates?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload modified jars or another files in your context folder (e.g. /ROOT)

[image: root_folder]

Then restart environment for applying changes.

Comment: Leo - It's not that jars are modified, it's that they're the same all the time. And uploading to Jelastic is a bit slow so it would be great to upload 1mb instead of 26mb.

Does this mean that I can leave the 20+ jars out of the war and just dump them in /ROOT?